# Allow only authorized code to call routines in library

Tags: c#, c++

Okay, I'll try to explain my use scenario here:
I have an implementation of a core library of which the lowest level access is APIs to enter data into DB which should be self contained as a sub-system. Now, for strange reasons this library is exposing critical parameters to this DB like Login ID, and Password, etc. It is intended to be only used for 'internal' code of some larger application developed by the same team, and the idea is to discourage use of these APIs by other 3rd party clients that have access to the same library in binary. This is the part where it gets more uglier. To implement these rather 'secret' functions a simple implementation of a previously decided secret key is devised. Say, code like this:

```
string secretKey = "blah...$$$";
string password = library::secretGetPwd(secretKey);
```

This is used in several places and the function only works if `secretKey` is correct. This does not seem like a good approach and can be easily found out. However, it does cause in several places warnings of several magic-strings which makes the `lint` tool very unhappy. The task at hand is to only remove these `lint` warnings. Could someone suggest some 'better' worse way to implement this?

Comment: `Could someone suggest some 'better' worse way to implement this?` Yeah: Don't store sensitive data in your dll/executable.

Comment: Agree and noted. Understood: need to correct this. Thanks! :)

Comment: is your `core library` in c++? and your caller in c#?

Comment: yes, the core library is in C++, and caller is in C#.

Comment: Is your assembly strong-named? An additional way is to check the callers and your assemblies public keys.

Comment: Yes, caller is strongly named I think. But why?

Comment: Normally, you use one (secret) key to give your assemblies a strong-name, 3rd parties do not have this key. So you can check, if the public key of the the calling assembly equals to the public key of the mixed mode C++/CLI assembly.

Comment: I could use this approach, but it is more or less similar to the present approach, except that it's 'key' should be better guarded. I don't know very much about strong name signing in C#, but I guess you are talking about public key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't answer your lint question, but you may be able to solve your larger problem this way:

First, strongly sign all of your stuff. Then you can look through the calling stack to see the assembly calling the code, and validate it's yours (the code uses the public keys to validate that it's yours [maybe not a good way]). Is this 100% secure? I doubt it.

```
    //This code relies on the public keys of the two assemblies to be the same.
    System::Diagnostics::StackTrace^ st = gcnew System::Diagnostics::StackTrace();
    System::Reflection::Assembly ^ otherAsm = st->GetFrame(1)->GetMethod()->Module->Assembly;
    array<unsigned char, 1> ^ otherKey = otherAsm->GetName()->GetPublicKey();

    System::Reflection::Assembly ^ thisAsm = st->GetFrame(0)->GetMethod()->Module->Assembly;
    array<unsigned char, 1> ^ thisKey = thisAsm->GetName()->GetPublicKey();

    for (int i = 0; i < thisKey->Length; i++)
    {
        if (otherKey[i] != thisKey[i])
            throw gcnew Exception();
    }
```

Comment: Understood! This code traverses through the whole call stack to check if anything did not have the same public key, then throw exception. Thanks for the implementation. I'll look for some more approaches till I finalize workaround.

Comment: It only checks the current frame and the previous one. You could change it to check the whole stack, but that's likely unnecessary. You're most concerned about entry points, and the previous frame would be the foreign assembly.